# PowerBI aggregate value separate from column separation

Tags: powerbi

Ho can I separate my value aggregation from columns in PBI. So, basically what I want is to make cnt column separate from row_number separation. For the first row cnt is actually 12, and then separation by row_numbers with dates and sums

*P.S. can't provide you with data, due to NDAs*

[image]